# How To Implement 2D Perspective Within a 3D Space (CSS & jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, math

I've been looking around for a solution to a problem which I've been unable to solve after much research. It's rather hard to explain so I've provided what I've managed to achieve so far as well as a concept of what I'm trying to achieve.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

**What I've managed to produce so far:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Enijar/f4TTY/)

**The problem:**

I'm trying to achieve a scrolling carousel menu. The window has 3 images (the one above is the second image). The window scrolls on it's x-axis. While it's scrolling the boxes should animate around a 360 degree ellipse. Here is the code for that functionality:

```
// Return degrees relative to window scroll.
// Scroll left 0 = 0 degrees and max scroll left = 360 degrees
this.degrees = function(windowScrollX, windowWidth, maxScrollX) {
    var degrees = (windowScrollX / ((maxScrollX + windowWidth) / 360)) * 2;

    if(degrees > 360) {
        degrees = 360;
    }

    if(degrees < 0) {
        degrees = 0;
    }

    return degrees;
};
```

The boxes should reduce in scale when they are in the distance and increase when they come to the front.

I only need to support IE 10+ for this client. I've been using CSS3 animations and tried the Canvas, all to no avail. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at parallax.js/stellar.js/etc or are you trying to do this yourself as an exercise?

Comment: @CaseyFalk Me and my colleagues have already looked into parallax, however that's not what we're trying to achieve here. We're tying to achieve animation around a 360 degree ellipse on the user scrolling on the x-axis. No parallax library I know of or have searched for offers anything like what we're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thought about using three.js ?

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Your JSfiddle seems to do what you are requesting.

Comment: @2pha This website needs to work on mobile so that option isn't viable because of the performance costs.

Comment: @Pitchinnate The JSFiddle distorts the divs as it's set to 3d transforms. We're trying to achieve what's in the image in my OP (2D divs).

Comment: Ahh gotcha understand you may want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Are you sure performance would be so bad with three.js? Have you tried it? I think if you are targeting modern phones that you could probably get acceptable results.

Comment: @2pha We've benchmarked three.js with other mobile projects that had 3D animation and it was too slow and clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get them all to face to the front you can rotate, then translate then rotate back again eg

```
.ring > .two {
    transform: rotateY(40deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-40deg);
}
```

In the rotateMenu function use something like

```
this.rotateMenu = function(degrees) {
    var d1 = degrees;
    var d2 = degrees+40;
    var d3 = degrees+80;
    var d4 = degrees+120;
    var d5 = degrees+160;
    var d6 = degrees+200;
    var d7 = degrees+240;
    var d8 = degrees+280;
    var d9 = degrees+320;

    $( '.ring > .one').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d1 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d1 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .two').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d2 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d2 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .three').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d3 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d3 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .four').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d4 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d4 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .five').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d5 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d5 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .six').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d6 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d6 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .seven').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d7 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d7 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .eight').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d8 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d8 +'deg'); 
    $( '.ring > .nine').css('transform', 'rotateY('+ d9 +'deg) translateZ(380px) rotateY(-'+ d9 +'deg'); 
};
```

Comment: Completely forgot you could rotate back again. Thank you for this.